# Gettign error while returning elements in render() function React+redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to print list as per the condition like 
If I have 2 set of track's 
1 ) featured 
2) nonFeatured

if featured track is available then i want to append

```
       <li>Featured Track</li>
```

before feature track list.

and  if nonFeatured tracks are available then

```
       <li> Other tracks</li>
```

before the list

So the output will be -

```
   <ul>
      <li>Featured Track</li>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
      <li>Other tracks</li>
     <li>1</li>
  </ul>
```

Below is my code snippet.

```
  render() {
    // Feature tracks and tracks are sorted track lists from currentTracks array. CurrentTracks contains both types.

    let {featureTracks, tracks, currentTracks}  = this.props.currentTracks
    let errorMessage = currentTracks.error
    let races = null
    if(_.isArray(currentTracks.tracks) && !_.isEmpty(currentTracks.tracks)) {
        races = (
            <ul className="currentRacesDropdownList animated">
                //Code to return feature track
                if(_.isArray(featureTracks) && !_.isEmpty(featureTracks)) {
                    return (
                        <li className="dropDownHeading ttFont fontRed">
                            Featured Tracks (5)
                        </li>
                        { featureTracks.map((track, key) => <RaceLineItem key={key} track={track} /> )}
                    )
                }
                if(_.isArray(tracks) && !_.isEmpty(tracks)) {
                    //Code to return other track
                    return (
                        <li className="dropDownHeading ttFont fontRed">
                            All Other Tracks (5)
                        </li>
                        { tracks.map((track, key) => <RaceLineItem key={key} track={track} /> )}
                    )
                }
            </ul>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {races}
            {errorMessage}
        </div>


    )
}
```

But I am getting error in return statement after if()

Just same question in other way please have a look at below example .

```
  I have below array , and if track is feature then i want to print it under "Feature" headline , and if track is non feature then i want to print it under "Other" headline.       
 var a = [{
        isFeature:true,
        name: 'abc'

     },{
       isFeature:false,
       name: 'xyz'

     },{
      isFeature: false,
      name: 'bpl'
 }]
```

And on react I want to render it in below html format -

```
   <ul>
     <li>Feature</li> 
     <li>abc</li> 
     <li>xyz</li>
     <li>Non Feature</li> 
     <li>bpl</li>  
   </ul>
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Module build failed: SyntaxError:

                  <ul className="currentRacesDropdownList animated">
                    if(_.isArray(featureTracks) && !_.isEmpty(featureTracks)) {
                        return (
                       ^

Its syntax error near return

Comment: @BravoZulu I am trying to return 2 different sets of list in <ul></ul> tag. If user get feature tracks then we have to print "feature track" in <li> and then to print all the list belong to that set. same for other track. (But in same <ul></ul>

Comment: What are you getting in `featureTracks, tracks en currentTracks`? Show that code.

Comment: in featureTrack and tracks list ,I am getting array of track .
Thats what i want to print if available . I have updated my code.

Comment: If you put console.log like `console.log(this.props.currentTracks)` above `let errorMessage = currentTracks.error`, what you see in console?

Comment: @Boky : I have updated my question and exactly written what structure i want .Please check at the end of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) methods to do it on a cleaner way. You can try something like this :

```
let a = [{
     isFeature:true,
        name: 'abc'

     },{
       isFeature:false,
       name: 'xyz '

     },{
      isFeature: false,
      name: 'bpl'
 }]

class Test extends React.Component {
        render() {

           let data  = this.props.data;
           let races = null;

           if(data.length > 0){
                races = <div>
                            <div>Featured</div>
                            {data.map(item => item).filter(f => f.isFeature)}
                            <div>Non featured</div>
                            {data.map(item => item).filter(f => !f.isFeature)}
                        </div>
           }

           return races
        }  
}

React.render(<Test data={a}/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1453/).

**UPDATE**

Now the results will be shown only if they exists.

```
let a = [{
     isFeature:true,
        name: 'abc'

     },{
       isFeature:false,
       name: 'xyz '

     },{
      isFeature: false,
      name: 'bpl'
 }]

class Test extends React.Component {
        render() {

    let data  = this.props.data;
    let races = null;

    if(data.length > 0){
        let featured = data.map(item => item).filter(f => f.isFeature).length > 0 ? <div><div>Featured</div>{data.map(item => item).filter(f => f.isFeature)}</div> : "";

        let nonFeatured = data.map(item => item).filter(f => !f.isFeature).length > 0 ? <div><div>Non Featured</div>{data.map(item => item).filter(f => !f.isFeature)}</div> : "";

        races = <div>
                {featured}
                {nonFeatured}
            </div>
    }
    return races
}
}

React.render(<Test data={a}/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1472/).

Comment: If there is no featured track then "Featured" heading should not come.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix JSX with arbitrary statements like `if...else` or `return`s.

Instead, use a ternary expression:

```
<ul className="currentRacesDropdownList animated">
    {(_.isArray(featureTracks) && !_.isEmpty(featureTracks)) ?
        <span>
            <li className="dropDownHeading ttFont fontRed">
                Featured Tracks (5)
            </li>
            { featureTracks.map((track, key) => <RaceLineItem key={key} track={track} /> )}
        </span>
    : null}

    ...
</ul>
```

Comment: it is giving syntax error near "  { featureTracks.map((track, key) => <RaceLineItem key={key} track={track} /> )}
 "

Comment: I think here jsx needs every thing in opening and closing tag like e.g : <li>{code}</li>  but current structure in your code  is like <li>abcd/li> {code}

Comment: You are right, the expression needs to return a single node. See my updated example, wrapping the two elements in a `<span>` solves the issue.